# ¿Como saber el tamaño de un vector en C++?

Tags: c++, array

Estaba haciendo un programa en C++ para entretenerme el cual incluye vectores. Necesito obtener el tamaño del vector. Alguien podría ayudarme a obtener dicho valor?

Comment: Se ve que ni si quiera haz intentado buscar en google

Comment: `sizeof(vector)`

Comment: @abrahamhs claro que he buscado, pero no he dado con la respuesta que creo que estoy buscando. Pero gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para saber el tamaño de un arreglo puedes usar sizeof, cabe destacar que es un **operador** no una función, que te devuelve el tamaño de almacenamiento que ocupa cualquier tipo de dato.

Su sintaxis es la siguiente:

- sizeof *variable*
- sizeof *(tipo de dato)*

Podemos ver un ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 int v[4];
 cout<<sizeof v <<endl;

}
```

La salida del programa será 16, ya que está agarrando el tamaño del dato entero que vale 4 bytes y lo multiplica por los 4 espacios que tiene el arreglo. Espero te sea de ayuda

Otro ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
 cout<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
 //la salida del programa será 
}
```

Aquí la salida del programa es 4, como dije anteriormente te mostrará el tamaño que ocupa en memoria el tipo de dato 4bytes.

Comment: ¿Y si es [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? ¿Y si es [`std::array`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Bueno mi estimado, mis conocimientos no llegan a ese nivel, no sabría responderte, si quieres agregarlo a la respuesta, bienvenido sea

Comment: El problema es que no sabemos qué tamaño quiere @GallinaSinCabeza ¿Quiere el de una formación? ¿Quiere el de un vector? ¿Quiere el de un array? ú_ù

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster si hubieras leído la pregunta que he formulado no te harías esas cuestiones. ;)

Comment: @GallinaSinCabeza me hago esas cuestiones porque tu pregunta no es nada clara. Un *vector* puede significar muchas cosas según el contexto y según tus conocimientos incluso según la versión de C++ que compiles.